# Use public dns of amazon VM as site url for a Facebook app

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I host a simple AWS vm as a test environment that hosts a website. When you go to the public dns of the VM you arrive at the website. This website allows you to connect to Facebook. The public dns is in the format of: `ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

For the test environment, I have setup a testapp in the developer console of Facebook and I use the public dns to the testvm as the website url. I also added this dns as the app domain.

`app domain: ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

`site URL: http://ec2-52-58-70-0.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/`

But if I connect to FB I get the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
   "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: URL kan niet worden geladen",
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "code": 191,
   "fbtrace_id": "CNGFoAnXcMA"
 }
}
```

This error is typically returned if you wrongly setup the website url. But it does work similarly in the real production app and with another testapp that uses localhost. I am sure I use the correct app secret for the test environment.

How do I configure FB to accept the redirect url originating from a aws vm?

Comment: What exactly triggers that error message?

Comment: When you open the connect to facebook login link. You should arrive at the login page for facebook. So you are actually at that moment not on my website.

Comment: Yeah, but where do you get that error message? It looks like JSON, so I assume it is rather not directly displayed as such on the page.

Comment: When you open the window to Facebook. So on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

couldn't remember exactly but callback URL should return 200 code, otw you may hit such errors.

Comment: The callback URL does return code 200 and every thing works using localhost.